# Python retry equivalent in Java

Tags: java, try-catch

I am very new to java and I am trying out error handling. I am pretty proficent in python and I know the error handling in python would go

```
while True:
      try:
          *some code*         
      except IndexError:
             continue
             break
```

I would like to know what the equivalent of a retry loop after exception is in java

EDIT: 
This is what I have so far, however whenever a exception is thrown it does an infinite loop saying "Enter an Short: Error Try again."

```
while(true)
    {
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter an Short: "); //SHORT
            short myShort = reader.nextShort();
            System.out.println(myShort);
            break;
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Try again.");
            continue;
        }
    }
```

To clarify what exactly I would like is. When "InputMismatchException" is thrown the loop re runs and prompts the user again and it does this until the user gives the correct input. I hope that clarifies what I would like it to do.

Comment: break it down, search java while loop example, search java try/catch example and join the two together

Comment: Have a look at the Java equivalents for the individual parts and apply what you've learned. The result should look very similar to python with some additional curly braces (and parantheses).

Comment: It seems the `Scanner` (I'm assuming `reader` is a `Scanner`) doesn't move forward when it fails to parse. This means every time you call `nextShort()` after an error it tries to parse the same input again. Try skipping (via `Scanner.skip`) the current line when an error occurs.

Comment: @Slaw THANK YOU that was totally it. I initialized scanner inside the while loop then closed it right before the break and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the help of @Slaw he determined that scanner would keep inputting the same value unless I closed it at the end of the loop and here is the working code.

```
while (true)
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        try
        {
            System.out.print("Enter an Short: "); //SHORT
            short myShort = reader.nextShort();
            System.out.println(myShort);
            reader.close();
            break;
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error Try again.");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As your question asks about error handling and you showed `IndexError` as an example, the equivalent in Java could be:

```
try {
    //*some code*
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
    //handleYourExceptionHere(exception);
}
```

About `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, you take a look [here, in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html). About Exceptions, in general, you can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html).

EDIT, according to your question edition, adding more information...

```
while(true)
{
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter a short: ");
        short myShort = reader.nextShort();
        System.out.println(myShort);
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Error! Try again.");
        //Handle the exception here...
        break;
    }
}
```

In this case, when the `InputMismatchException` occurs, the error message is exhibited and the `break` should leave the loop. I do not know yet if I understand well what you are asking, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I have found how to do that. But I am wondering how to retry that loop after it throws the error.

Comment: Do you want go out of the loop always when some exception occurs? It is not well clear what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is almost good as @Thomas mentioned. Just need to add some brackets and semicolons. It should look line following code.

```
while(true){
    try{
        // some code
        break; // Prevent infinite loop, success should break from the loop
    } catch(Exception e) { // This would catch all exception, you can narrow it down ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        continue;
    }
}
```